# C programming… Linked List Pointer Iteration

Tags: c, debugging, pointers, linked-list

Hello I have the following functions defined:

```
head();
traverse(struct *);
```

I'm concerned that when iterating through the list it is being modified.

```
void tail()
{
    n3.next = (struct entry*) 0xff;
}

void traverse(struct entry *listPt)
{
    while(listPt != (struct entry *) 0xff)
    {
        printf("%i\n", listPt->value);
        listPt = listPt->next;
    }
}
```

Should I use a different algorithm to iterate the list? Is it more beneficial to copy the list?

Is the following expression from the while loop overwritten existing (values) memory?

```
listPt = listPt->next;
```

Comment: Why `0xff` instead of `NULL`?

Comment: I wanted to look at the value in gdb. Using 0xff allowed me to see a distinct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement overrides only local variable `listPt` declared as a function parameter

```
struct entry *listPt
```

It does not modify the list itself.

Function parameters are its local variables. The function deals with copies of its arguments. Any changing of a parameter does not influence on the corresponding argument.

Consider

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func( int *p )
{
    int y = 20;

    p = &y;

    printf( "%d\n", *p );  // prints 20
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 10;
    int *px = &x;

    printf( "%d\n", *px );    // prints 10;

    func( px );

    printf( "%d\n", *px );    // prints 10;
}
```

Comment: So in C# passing a object by Ref to a method propagates changes to any code that holds references to that object. What is the difference with  a pointer. Is it essentially the same as passing a piece of memory that references some data?

Comment: @d_blk It is the same as passing a reference to an object in C#. The original reference iitself that is passed as an argument will not be changed but the object that is refered to by the reference will be changed.

Comment: @d_blk On the other hand if pass a reference by reference in C# that is if the corresponding parameter will have specifier ref then also the original refernce itself can be changed, It looks the same as if you passed a pointer to pointer in C. For example void traverse(struct entry **listPt); and inside the function you changed the value of the expression *listPt

Answer (score -2):

No this algorithm is ok, you wont modify the list.
If you want to modify you have to set the function header like this `void traverse(struct entry * & listPt)`

Comment: you mean `void traverse(struct entry **listPt)`, no ?

Comment: Yeah right in c but in c++ you can use & and it is easier to use